# Trouble retrieving coordinates in Swift from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am new to programming so apologies for any ignorance on my part. I am also sure there are many best practices I am not following, but my problem is more specific. I am making a contacts app for a specific demographic. Part of the app is a map view that shows pins of every contact. When I save a new person I am geocoding the address like this:

```
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: self.managedObjectContext)
    let record = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: self.managedObjectContext)

geocoder.geocodeAddressString(rvAddress, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if((error) != nil){
            print("Error", error!)
        }
        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
        let rvCoordinates = placemark.location!.coordinate
        let rvLatitude = rvCoordinates.latitude
        let rvLongitude = rvCoordinates.longitude
        record.setValue(rvLatitude, forKey: "latitude")
        record.setValue(rvLongitude, forKey: "longitude")    
        }    
    })
```

Where fetched people is populated in the segue from the initial table view to the map view controller `viewController.fetchedPeople = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` to `var fetchedPeople: [Person]?` In the map view controller class. I have a for loop like this in the map view controller :

```
for people in  fetchedPeople! {
            let firstName = people.value(forKey: "firstName") as? String
            let lastName = people.value(forKey: "lastName") as? String
            let street = people.value(forKey: "street") as? String
            let rvLatitude = people.value(forKey: "latitude") as? Double
            let rvLongitude = people.value(forKey: "longitude") as? Double
            print("LAT: \(rvLatitude!) LONG: \(rvLongitude!)")
            let rvCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: rvLatitude!, longitude: rvLongitude!)

            var personName: String!
            var personAddress: String!
            if firstName != nil {
                personName = firstName! + " " + lastName!
            } else {
                personName = lastName!
            }
            print(personName)

            personAddress = street!

            let mapPerson = MapPerson(title: personName, locationName: personAddress, coordinate: rvCoordinates)
           //mapPeopleArray.append(mapPerson)
           mapView.addAnnotation(mapPerson)
            print(rvCoordinates)
```

When i initially add contacts everything is great. Pins drop as expected. Console shows:

```
LAT: 41.1656913 LONG: -81.8692497
Eric Madzay
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.165691299999999, longitude: -81.869249699999997)
LAT: 41.253647 LONG: -81.875974
Ethan Madzay
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.253647000000001, longitude: -81.875973999999999)
LAT: 41.203748 LONG: -81.858518
Work
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.203747999999997, longitude: -81.858518000000004)'
```

However, when I close the app, rerun, and open map view only some of the pins drop. I make zero changes to anything. Merely close/open and navigate to view. Console reads:

```
LAT: 41.253647 LONG: -81.875974
Ethan Madzay
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.253647000000001, longitude: -81.875973999999999)
LAT: 41.1656913 LONG: -81.8692497
Eric Madzay
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.165691299999999, longitude: -81.869249699999997)
LAT: 0.0 LONG: 0.0
Work
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
```

This is only one example but seems to show off my problem the best. I know I must be missing something or not understanding how something functions, I just cannot figure it out myself for the life of me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details? for example what is `record` in the `geocoder.geocodeAddressString` function? and how is the array `people` filled? I 'm afraid this question is unsolvable without those details :)

Comment: Edited to show those details. If more is still required let me know, again apologies for the headache, Im new at this.

Comment: Where and when do you save the context?  It looks like the save happens after adding the new Person, but before the geocoder's completion handler sets the corresponding lat/long values.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you pbasdf that was what I didn't understand, how the completion handler was working. Saving the context also within the geocode block fixed my problem. Thank you!